# Can I hide/show the black border around a selected cell?

Tags: vba, excel

If we protect sheets using the ribbon UI, and if every cell is locked or no selection is enabled, the rectangle cursor disappears.

But since I have some cells interact with the user, I am not going to lock every cell. Now the rectangle only appear on the unlocked cells.

And since I have to make those locked cells selectable by VBA, the following code was added:

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Protect Password:="******", _
    UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

And now since VBA can select every cell, no matter locked or unlocked, that rectangle cursor appears everywhere.

Now I want that rectangle itself to be hidden; is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps a bit too quick.  Please tell a little more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user1543250: If you want to hide the rect cursor then how will the user know which is the active cell?

Comment: @SiddharthRout See my comment and the OP's response below my answer.

Comment: @DougGlancy: I had to re-read many time before I understood the actual query (Not sure if I have still understood it correctly) The user wants Excel not to show the Black Rectangle which you get when you select a cell for unlocked cells?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, no black rectangle, similar to if EnableSelection is xlNoSelection, but with unlocked cells that can be selected.  The question has been edited a couple of times.  When I answered, it was just how to make it act like unchecking "Select Unlocked Cells" in the Protect dialog.

Comment: @DougGlancy: Aha! AFAIK you are correct. You cannot do it without disabling the ability to enter text in Unlocked cells.

Answer (score 1):

Add this bit of code:

```
Worksheets("sheet1").EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
```

Comment: Your question says "If we protect sheets using the ribbon UI, and if there is no cell unlocked, that rectangle cursor would disappear."  Now you say you're not going to lock every cell.  Which is true?  Anyways that's the only way I can come up with.

Comment: I don't think you can do it.  Also, it seems like a bad idea to hide the cursor from the user.  It will just make it hard for them to see what they are doing.  Good luck!

Comment: Are you using select and active statements throughout your code?

Answer (score 0):

I can't make it vanish completely, but I can hide it well.
I note from a comment that you highlight the current cell, so this code added to that highlighting should help hide the cursor:

```
' Code generated by record macro, and not tidied up
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
```

This will turn the border black, and it will be white (with a very thin black outline) when the cell is selected.

The alternative would be to change all the cells to have a grey thick outline, so it will have the same color outline when the box is selected. Programatically, the change to the code would be to remove the colorindex line, and add

```
    .ThemeColor = 1
```

in its place, and to change the TintAndShade line to this:

```
    .TintAndShade = -0.5
```

regardless of the method used, you will still end up with a thin black line in the current cell.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to actually hide the rectangle.

Comment: It's not a function added to vba there's really not much to add. Of course you can try to work around it by displacing it in any sort but to answer the question, No, it's not possible to show/hide the black selection box in excel-vba

Answer (score -1):

1) Hide A Column

2) Move to A1

Answer (score -2):

I don't know who wrote this so i could give credit, but it seems to work.

```
Private Declare Function ShowCursor Lib "USER32" _ 
(ByVal fShow As Integer) As Integer 

Sub hide() 
    While ShowCursor(False) >= 0 
    Wend 
End Sub 

Sub show() 
    While ShowCursor(True) < 0 
    Wend 
End Sub
```

Comment: I know, but in my case it was intended to hide the cursor.